# Google apps not working on mobile data, although non-Google apps are working

Tags: samsung, google, mobile-data

I have a strange problem on my Samsung J2 Android phone. Although apps like WhatsApp and some games which require Internet work, none of the Google Apps like Google, Chrome, YouTube and Play Store are working. Whenever I open the Google apps, it shows "Check your internet connection"  although my mobile data is on. But, on connecting my phone to a Wi-Fi network, these apps work. How can I fix this?

P.S. One more important thing: When I open Chrome, I get a message saying ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED.

Comment: Your carrier might be blocking Google domains. Do a `ping` and/or `dig` on few of the commonly accessed Google domains. Also check `logcat` to see what errors Google apps throw when a connection fails.

Comment: @irfanLatif how do you do that?

Comment: Does anyone else have a solution? I will definitely award the bounty to the one who solves my problem.

Comment: In which country do you live and which mobile network provider do you use? If there is a man-in-the-middle attack (e.g. by your government) on the mobile network then Google services will not work because they use certificate pinning. Other apps will as ling as the used server certificate is trusted by the device.

Comment: I live in India, but I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED.

This obviously has to do something with proxies. Either you set a proxy through your cellular data setting or some application has put phone in tunneling (VPN etc).

And obviously google services are highly sensitive to proxy IPs. Check if your IP is what your ISP has provided. Google services are often buggy with cache so try clearing some cache as well.

Changing APNs might also work, sometimes Google might get sensitive of your real IP. Do a hotspot sharing and check google services with that IP on other devices.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I am guessing that resetting my APNs will do it, but what does resetting an APN mean? Will it cause any problem in my phone?

Comment: @AD-1 Hey,APNs are literally pre-sent configs which are sent by providers, most of time(at least in my country) you can prompt your ISP to resend APN through USSD. I highly recommend you to make a contact with ISP for this purpose. Ports,Protocols and proxies are set in APNs

Comment: Do you know about the same in India? What should we do in India about this?

Comment: hey, I awarded you the bounty. Congrats!

Comment: @AD-1 Hey! Thanks for that, this might be of a help [check](https://www.mobileussdcodes.com/get-all-sim-gprs-internet-settings-airtel-aircel-idea-bsnl-mts-mtnl-reliance-vodafone-reliance/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, @iBUYPOWER!

Answer (score 3):

Check if google domain is not blocked by the network you are using , also try resting network settings , and try to delete the configuration settings that has been provided by your service provider automatically and call the help line ask them to resend you the internet settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off data saver mode. And try to use Google apps.
Your other apps are working. But you can reset network setting. You can change APN.

Go to setting / mobile network / Access point name. Every carrier has APN. You can try all APN.

Force stop google app and than start again. Clear cache and storage for apps.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score -2):

i think auto sync is turn off, go to accounts and turn auto sync on

Comment: Chrome, YouTube and Play Store don't need sync to work. Plus, if sync was the problem it should be exhibiting when Wi-Fi was being used. The problem with OP is only when the device is using mobile data.

Comment: This is definitely not the problem. This is a recent problem for me, but my auto-sync has always been turned off.